# Proof for a relation

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, relations

Define a relationship $R$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ by declaring that $xRy$ if and only if $x^2 \equiv y^2 (mod 4)$. Prove that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

I'm unsure of where to start with this question.

Comment: It's always a good start to write down precisely and formally the definitions of these three properties.

Comment: Start with reflexive. We want to show that $xRx$ for all $x$, that is, $4$ divides $x^2-x^2$. It sure does.

Comment: Besides brute-force verification, you can prove $\, 4\mid x^2-y^2 \iff 2\mid x-y,\,$ and the latter is well-known to be an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Not to hard to prove that:

1. $x^2\equiv x^2($mod $4)$ (reflexivity)
2. $x^2\equiv y^2($mod $4)\Rightarrow y^2\equiv x^2($mod $4)$ (symmetric)
3. And $x^2\equiv y^2($mod $4)\wedge y^2\equiv z^2($mod $4)\Rightarrow x^2\equiv z^2($mod $4)$ (transitiv)